# heavy saga request freezes the application

Tags: multithreading, react-redux, react-native, redux-saga

Assume i have a heavy saga request that casues to excessive number of pending callbacks warning which burden the UI/JS bridge and freezes my application.
The saga request is executes on the background and should not affect the application.
Is there a way to run that saga request on a diffrent thread that the app response won't compromise as it does now?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the saga doing?

Comment: thanks for responding @WillJenkins!
my saga needs to fetch like  700 images in the background from a minio server, get each image base64 and then set the image to asyncStorage as key:value (imageUrl:imageBase64)